# Two subsequent jquery ajax requests not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

Captcha validation is working then mail sending ajax is not working and it's not showing either success message nor the failure message. Please find the entire code (as I am not able to paste the code here as its giving some formatting error).

http://demo.cateringandevents.in/contactusform.htm

Please suggest a better validation method for this HTML form.

Comment: Please post your code. Links are always a bad idea. Use http://jsbeautifier.org/ and post the code here (mark your code in the answer and press crtl+k). If it doesn't work out, don't worry, there are a lot of people ready to help and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement the error callback option. This will provide you with the necessary error information. You are now only implementing the success callback which not gets called when something went wrong. Optionally you can also implement the complete callback which will always be called after the ajax request was send.

```
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "thankyou.php",
      data: sData,
      success: function () {
          // Yeah!
      },
      error: function(){
          // oops
      }
 });
```

Comment: Is your error callback called? In other words, if you put a breakpoint in there (or add a console log), is your code executing paused there?

Comment: What's that for statement? I'm trying to help you solving this issue. You can at least put in some effort to understand what is going on before you start to scream.

Comment: yes I am following whatever you are telling but still its the same status ....please help me on this ...

Comment: So...to repeat my question, is it calling the error callback?

Answer (score 0):

The next function is returning `false` always. You must think in an asynchronous way, when you summon the ajax call, the program continues its execution, returns false and after a while (whenever the server response), the success callback return true, but none is listening for it anymore..

```
function validateCaptach() {
    if (validateForm()) {
        var captchaval = $("#verificationcode").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "captchacheck.php",
            async: false, // Lets make it synchronous
            data: {
                verificationcode: captchaval
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == "SUCCESS") {
                    alert("captchacheck sucess..");
                    return true;
                } else {
                    alert("The security code you typed was wrong. Please try again.");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    return false; // No matter what happends it always return false
}
```

Remove the last return and try again with `async: false,` (I already added to the previous snippet) it will forze the browser to stop untill it gets a response and then it will continue the normal execution of your program into the success callback.

If the previous comment doesn't work ([async](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) option seems to don't work in every case) you can try to nest both functions in one:

```
function submitform() {
    if (validateForm()) {
        var captchaval = $("#verificationcode").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "captchacheck.php",
            data: {
                verificationcode: captchaval
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data == "SUCCESS") {
                    alert("captchacheck sucess..");
                    sendForm(); // New function
                } else
                    alert("The security code you typed was wrong. Please try again.");
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { // New error handler
                alert("Ouch! something went wrong checking the captcha?. " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }
}

function sendForm() {
    var sData = $("#RegisterUserForm").serialize();
    alert('i am here to process..');  
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "thankyou.php",
        data: sData,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == "YESSUCCESS")
                alert("Your Query has been sent..");
            else
                alert("some error please type again...");
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { // New error handler
            alert("Ouch! something went wrong sending the form?. " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: sorry to say that the both the way its not responding .. plese its killing me for 5 hrs ..

Comment: @user601140 I edited completely my post, check with that approach and lets see what happend. As you can see it always returns false, so the next ajax call is never summoned.

Comment: I sorry for the late . I have tried with your changes .still the same result is coming ..please check if you want . Url is

Comment: plese find the url www.demo.cateringandevents.in/contactusform.htm

Comment: @user601140 I made another change, nesting both functions, check it out ;)